# Trouble with API authentication and cookie handling in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Dart/Flutter project where I need to authenticate with an API and handle cookies for subsequent requests. However, I'm encountering some issues and could use some guidance.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- Authenticate with the API using a cookie-based authentication mechanism.
- Store and manage the cookies for subsequent requests.
- Make authenticated GET requests to fetch data from the API.

I've implemented a `ApiBaseHelper` class that handles API requests and cookie management. However, I'm facing the following problems:

1. I'm not sure how to correctly handle and store cookies received from the API during authentication.
2. Subsequent requests don't seem to include the cookies, resulting in authentication failures.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to address these issues. Are there any best practices for handling cookies and authentication in Dart/Flutter?
my problem is the store and retrieve process of my ApiBaseHelper works but the format of my stored value does not match the necessary format : this is my error when i'm trying to modify my profile : ```
response is : {"code":5001,"description":"Server side error : JsonWebTokenError: invalid token","success":false,"date":"2023-05-21T13:36:21.599Z"}

```
Here's a simplified version of my `ApiBaseHelper` class for reference:
```

````
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'package:sultan_mobile_app/data/repos/auth_repos.dart';
import '../../helpers/utils.dart';
import 'exceptions.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

class ApiBaseHelper {
  final String _baseUrl = "http://162.19.152.78:5000/*****my_backend_url*****-v1/";
  //late Map<String, String> _headers;

  static ApiBaseHelper shared = ApiBaseHelper();
  final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  late Map<String, String> headers = {};
  //Map<String, String> headers = {};
  late CookieJar cookieJar;

  ApiBaseHelper() {
    cookieJar = CookieJar();
  }
  _showErrorToast(String message) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: message,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white);
  }

  //  _initiateHeaders({bool needsAuth = true}) async {
  //  headers = {};
  //  if (needsAuth) {
  //    String? authToken = await storage.read(key: "token");
  //    if (authToken != null) {
  //      headers['x-sultan-token'] = authToken;
  //    }
  //  }
  //  headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
  //  headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
//
  //  // Load stored cookies
  //  String? cookiesString = await storage.read(key: "token");
  //  print(cookiesString);
//
  //  if (cookiesString != null) {
  //    List<Cookie> storedCookies = _parseCookies(cookiesString);
  //    cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), storedCookies);
  //  }
  //  return headers;
  //}
  Future<Map<String, String>> _initiateHeaders({bool needsAuth = true}) async {
    headers = {};

    if (needsAuth) {
      String? authToken = await storage.read(key: "Cookie");
      if (authToken != null) {
        headers['Cookie'] = authToken;
      }
    }

    headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

    // Load stored cookies
    String? cookiesString = await storage.read(key: "Cookie");

    if (cookiesString != null) {
      List<Cookie> storedCookies = _parseCookies(cookiesString);
      cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), storedCookies);
    }

    return headers;
  }

  /*Future<Map<String, String>> _initiateHeaders({bool needsAuth = true}) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {};

    if (needsAuth) {
      String? authToken = await storage.read(key: AuthRepository.currentUser.token!);
      if (authToken != null) {
        headers['x-sultan-token'] = authToken;
      }
    }

    headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

    // Load stored cookies
    String? cookiesString = await storage.read(key: 'cookies');
    if (cookiesString != null) {
      List<Cookie> storedCookies = _parseCookies(cookiesString);
      cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), storedCookies);
    }

    return headers;
  }*/
Future<void> _saveCookies() async {
    List<Cookie> cookies = await cookieJar.loadForRequest(Uri.parse(_baseUrl));
    String cookiesString = _formatCookies(cookies);

    await storage.write(key: 'Cookie', value: cookiesString);
  }

  List<Cookie> _parseCookies(String cookiesString) {
    List<Cookie> cookies = [];
    List<String> cookieStrings = cookiesString.split(';');
    for (String cookieString in cookieStrings) {
      List<String> cookieParts = cookieString.split('=');
      if (cookieParts.length == 2) {
        Cookie cookie = Cookie(cookieParts[0].trim(), cookieParts[1].trim());
        cookies.add(cookie);
      }
    }
    return cookies;
  }

  String _formatCookies(List<Cookie> cookies) {
    List<String> cookieStrings =
        cookies.map((cookie) => '${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}').toList();
        print('cookies:${cookieStrings}');
    return cookieStrings.join('; ');
  }
  /*  _initiateHeaders({bool needsAuth = true}) async {
    headers = {};
    if (needsAuth) {
      headers = {
        "x-sultan-token": "Bearer ${AuthRepository.currentUser.apiToken}"
      };
    }
    headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
  }
  Future<Map<String, String>> _initiateHeaders({bool needsAuth = true}) async {
    if (needsAuth) {
      String? authToken = await storage.read(key: 'token');
      print(authToken);
      if (authToken != null) {
        headers['x-sultan-token'] = authToken;
        print('____HEADERSCookies____:' + headers.toString());
      }
    }
    /*String? authToken = await storage.read(key: 'token');

    print(authToken);*/

    headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    print('____HEADERS____:' + headers.toString());
    return headers;
  }*/

  /* Future<dynamic> get(String url,
      {bool needsAuth = true, bool showLoader = false}) async {
    // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
    var responseJson;

    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: needsAuth);
    if (showLoader) {
      Utils.showLoader("Chargement...");
    }
    try {
      final response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url), headers: headers);
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("url is : $_baseUrl$url");
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("response is : ${response.body}");
      responseJson = _returnResponse(response);
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
    } on SocketException {
      _showErrorToast("Pas de connexion internet.");
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      throw FetchDataException('Pas de connexion internet.');
      // ignore: unused_catch_clause
    } on InvalidInputException catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      _showErrorToast("Vérifiez les champs");
    } on SessionExpiredException catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      throw SessionExpiredException(e);
    } catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      //_showErrorToast(e.toString());
    }
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    return responseJson;
  }*/
  Future<dynamic> get(String url,
      {bool needsAuth = true, bool showLoader = false}) async {
    var responseJson;

    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: needsAuth);
    if (showLoader) {
      Utils.showLoader("Chargement...");
    }
    try {
      final response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url), headers: headers);

      String? authToken = response.headers['set-cookie'];
      if (authToken != null) {
        // Create a new cookie with the authToken value
        Cookie authCookie = Cookie('x-sultan-token', authToken);
        // Save the cookie to the cookie jar
        cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), [authCookie]);
        await _saveCookies();
      }

      print("url is : $_baseUrl$url");
      print("response is : ${response.body}");
      responseJson = _returnResponse(response);
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
    } on SocketException {
      _showErrorToast("Pas de connexion internet.");
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      throw FetchDataException('Pas de connexion internet.');
    } on InvalidInputException catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      _showErrorToast("Vérifiez les champs");
    } on SessionExpiredException catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      throw SessionExpiredException(e);
    } catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      //_showErrorToast(e.toString());
    }
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    return responseJson;
  }

  Future<dynamic> delete(String url,
      {bool needsAuth = true, bool showLoader = false}) async {
    // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
    var responseJson;

    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: needsAuth);
    if (showLoader) {
      Utils.showLoader("Chargement...");
    }
    try {
      final response =
          await http.delete(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url), headers: headers);
      // Save cookies from response headers
      String? authToken = response.headers['x-sultan-token'];
      if (authToken != null) {
        // Create a new cookie with the authToken value
        Cookie authCookie = Cookie('x-sultan-token', authToken);
        // Save the cookie to the cookie jar
        cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), [authCookie]);
        await _saveCookies();
      }
    } on SocketException {
      _showErrorToast("Pas de connexion internet.");
      throw FetchDataException('Pas de connexion internet.');
      // ignore: unused_catch_clause
    } on InvalidInputException catch (e) {
      _showErrorToast("Vérifiez les champs");
    } on SessionExpiredException catch (e) {
      throw SessionExpiredException(e);
    } catch (e) {
      _showErrorToast("Erreur de connexion");
    }
    return responseJson;
  }

  Future<dynamic> post(String url, dynamic rBody,
      {bool needsAuth = true, showLoader = false}) async {
    // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
    var responseJson;
    if (showLoader) {
      Utils.showLoader("Chargement...");
    }
    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: needsAuth);
    try {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url),
          body: json.encode(rBody), headers: headers);
      String? authToken = response.headers['set-cookie'];
      if (authToken != null) {
        // Create a new cookie with the authToken value
        String sanitizedAuthToken =
            authToken.replaceAll(';' ' ', ''); // Remove semicolon if present
        Cookie authCookie = Cookie('x-sultan-token', sanitizedAuthToken);

        //Cookie authCookie = Cookie('x-sultan-token', authToken);
        print(authCookie);
        print("_____");
        print(authToken);
        print(authCookie);
        // Save the cookie to the cookie jar
        cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), [authCookie]);
        print(cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), [authCookie]));
        await _saveCookies();
      }
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("url is : $url");
        print("_____");
        print(authToken!.substring(15));
      }
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("response is : ${response.body}");
      }
      responseJson = _returnResponse(response);
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(response.statusCode);
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
    } on AppException catch (exception) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      AppExceptionResponse error = AppExceptionResponse.fromJson(
          json.decode(exception.message.toString()));
      return error;
    }
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    return responseJson;
  }

  /*Future<dynamic> put(String url, dynamic body,
      {bool needsAuth = true, showLoader = false}) async {
    // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
    //var responseJson;
    if (showLoader) {
      Utils.showLoader("Chargement...");
    }
    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: needsAuth);

    try {
      final response = await http.put(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url),
          body: json.encode(body), headers: headers);
              String? authToken = response.headers['x-sultan-token'];
      if (authToken != null) {
        // Create a new cookie with the authToken value
        Cookie authCookie = Cookie('x-sultan-token', authToken);
        // Save the cookie to the cookie jar
        cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), [authCookie]);
        await _saveCookies();
      }
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("url is : $url");
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("payload is : ${json.encode(body)}");
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("response is : ${response.body}");
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      responseJson = _returnResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      _showErrorToast("Pas de connexion internet.");
      throw FetchDataException('Pas de connexion internet.');
      // ignore: unused_catch_clause
    } on InvalidInputException catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      _showErrorToast("Vérifiez les champs");
    } catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(json.encode(e));
      _showErrorToast("Erreur de connexion.");
    }

    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    return responseJson;
  }*/
  Future<dynamic> put(String url, dynamic body,
      {bool needsAuth = true, showLoader = false}) async {
    var responseJson;
    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: needsAuth);

    if (showLoader) {
      Utils.showLoader("Chargement...");
    }

    try {
      final response = await http.put(
        Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url),
        headers: headers,
        body: jsonEncode(body),
      );

      String? authToken = response.headers['x-sultan-token'];
      if (authToken != null) {
        // Create a new cookie with the authToken value
        String sanitizedAuthToken =
            authToken.replaceAll(';' ' ', ''); // Remove semicolon if present
        Cookie authCookie = Cookie('x-sultan-token', sanitizedAuthToken);
        //Cookie authCookie = Cookie('x-sultan-token', authToken);
        cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), [authCookie]);
        await _saveCookies();
      }

      print("url is : $url");
      print("payload is : ${json.encode(body)}");
      print("response is : ${response.body}");
      responseJson = _returnResponse(response);
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      return _returnResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      _showErrorToast("Pas de connexion internet.");
      throw FetchDataException('Pas de connexion internet.');
    } on InvalidInputException catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      _showErrorToast("Vérifiez les champs");
      throw e; // Rethrow the exception
    } catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      return responseJson;
      /*print(json.encode(e));
      _showErrorToast("Erreur de connexion.");
      throw e; // Rethrow the exception*/
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> patch(String url, dynamic body,
      {bool needsAuth = true, showLoader = false}) async {
    // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
    var responseJson;
    if (showLoader) {
      Utils.showLoader("Chargement...");
    }
    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: needsAuth);

    try {
      final response = await http.patch(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url),
          body: json.encode(body), headers: headers);
      String? authToken = response.headers['x-sultan-token'];
      if (authToken != null) {
        // Create a new cookie with the authToken value
        Cookie authCookie = Cookie('x-sultan-token', authToken);
        // Save the cookie to the cookie jar
        cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(_baseUrl), [authCookie]);
        await _saveCookies();
      }
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("url is : $url");
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("payload is : ${json.encode(body)}");
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("response is : ${response.body}");
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      responseJson = _returnResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      _showErrorToast("Pas de connexion internet.");
      throw FetchDataException('Pas de connexion internet.');
      // ignore: unused_catch_clause
    } on InvalidInputException catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      _showErrorToast("Vérifiez les champs");
    } catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(json.encode(e));
      _showErrorToast("Erreur de connexion.");
    }
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    return responseJson;
  }

  /*Future<bool> asyncFileUpload(String url, File file,
      {String path = "photos"}) async {
    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: true);

    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
      "POST",
      Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url),
    );
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    var pic = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(path, file.path);
    request.files.add(pic);
    var response = await request.send();
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(responseString);
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (responseString != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> asyncFilesUpload(String url, List<File> file,
      {String path = "photos"}) async {
    await _initiateHeaders(needsAuth: true);

    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
      "POST",
      Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url),
    );
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
      request.files.add(
        http.MultipartFile(
            'attachments[]',
            File(file[i].path).readAsBytes().asStream(),
            File(file[i].path).lengthSync(),
            filename: file[i].path.split("/").last),
      );
    }
    var response = await request.send();
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(responseString);
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (responseString != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }*/

  Future<void> logout() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.clear(); // Clear local storage

    // Clear cookies from the cookie jar
    await cookieJar.deleteAll();
    await _saveCookies();

    // Perform additional logout actions, if any
    // For example, sending a logout request to the server
    /* try {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(LOGOUT_URL), // Replace with the actual logout URL
      headers: headers,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Logout successful
      // Additional handling, if needed
    } else {
      // Logout failed
      // Additional handling, if needed
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Error occurred during logout
    // Additional handling, if needed
  }*/
  }

  dynamic _returnResponse(http.Response response) {
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        return response;
      case 201:
        return response;
      case 204:
        return response;
      case 302:
        return Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: InvalidInputException(response.body.toString()).toString(),
        );
      case 400:
        return Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: InvalidInputException(response.body.toString()).toString(),
        );
      case 401:
        return Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: InvalidInputException(response.body.toString()).toString(),
        );
      case 403:
        return Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: InvalidInputException(response.body.toString()).toString(),
        );
      case 422:
        return Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: InvalidInputException(response.body.toString()).toString(),
        );
      case 420:
        return Utils.showErrorEmail("Email déjà utilisée!");
      // return _showErrorEmail("Email déjà utilisée");
      case 500:
        return Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: InvalidInputException(response.body.toString()).toString(),
        );
      default:
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print("error server ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  }
}
 in those line i'm trying to debug my stored values with print : 
print(authCookie);
        print("_____");
        print(authToken);
        print(authCookie);

and i get thoe results : 
 x-sultan-token=x-sultan-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6IlVzZXIgb25lIiwidXNlckVtYWlsIjoidXNlcjFAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcklEIjoiZjY1YjYzZDgtYmE5My00M2QwLTk4MzMtYTI1YWNhOTAwMjMxIiwiaXNBY3RpdmUiOnRydWUsImlzVmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImlzQmxvY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwibG9naW5EYXRlIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0yMVQxMzozNjowNC40MTlaIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg0Njc2MTY0fQ.NAWaU8j3bNbsySYRV29I4FurI0WO-z8DgfmPNIfFF9cPath=/; HttpOnly
I/flutter ( 4896): _____
I/flutter ( 4896): x-sultan-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6IlVzZXIgb25lIiwidXNlckVtYWlsIjoidXNlcjFAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcklEIjoiZjY1YjYzZDgtYmE5My00M2QwLTk4MzMtYTI1YWNhOTAwMjMxIiwiaXNBY3RpdmUiOnRydWUsImlzVmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImlzQmxvY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwibG9naW5EYXRlIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0yMVQxMzozNjowNC40MTlaIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg0Njc2MTY0fQ.NAWaU8j3bNbsySYRV29I4FurI0WO-z8DgfmPNIfFF9c; Path=/
I/flutter ( 4896): x-sultan-token=x-sultan-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6IlVzZXIgb25lIiwidXNlckVtYWlsIjoidXNlcjFAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcklEIjoiZjY1YjYzZDgtYmE5My00M2QwLTk4MzMtYTI1YWNhOTAwMjMxIiwiaXNBY3RpdmUiOnRydWUsImlzVmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImlzQmxvY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwibG9naW5EYXRlIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0yMVQxMzozNjowNC40MTlaIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg0Njc2MTY0fQ.NAWaU8j3bNbsySYRV29I4FurI0WO-z8DgfmPNIfFF9cPath=/; HttpOnly
I/flutter ( 4896): Instance of 'Future<void>'
I/flutter ( 4896): cookies:[eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6IlVzZXIgb25lIiwidXNlckVtYWlsIjoidXNlcjFAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcklEIjoiZjY1YjYzZDgtYmE5My00M2QwLTk4MzMtYTI1YWNhOTAwMjMxIiwiaXNBY3RpdmUiOnRydWUsImlzVmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImlzQmxvY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwibG9naW5EYXRlIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0yMVQxMzoyMzo0NS4xOThaIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg0Njc1NDI1fQ.59c5G3eNP4qw9QOFJYdiou05pjTAPPCYuNMOopCe6m0Path=/, eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6IlVzZXIgb25lIiwidXNlckVtYWlsIjoidXNlcjFAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcklEIjoiZjY1YjYzZDgtYmE5My00M2QwLTk4MzMtYTI1YWNhOTAwMjMxIiwiaXNBY3RpdmUiOnRydWUsImlzVmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImlzQmxvY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwibG9naW5EYXRlIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0yMVQxMzozNDoyNi4yNDBaIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg0Njc2MDY2fQ.ih9Lc4xkog7v1bgM8KG0tAKelajK4o5khnA90ww3EdYPath=/, x-sultan-token=x-sultan-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6IlVzZXIgb25lIiwidXNlckVtYWlsIjoidXNlcjFAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcklEIjoiZjY1YjYzZDgtYmE5My00M2QwLTk4MzMtYTI1YWNhOTAwMjMxIiwiaXNBY3RpdmUiOnRydWUsImlzVmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImlzQmxvY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwibG9naW5EY
i think the problem is with the "x-sultan-token=x-sultan-token=" prefix.
```
````

Thank you in advance for your help!